# How to convert this date string into a datetime date object?

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

I can't figure out why this date string throws an error when I try to convert it into a datetime object.

My date string is in the [standard ISO-8601 format](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html): `u'2013-11-05T20:24:51+0000'`

Apparent format based on Python's [strptime documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior): `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z'`

But for some reason, when I run:

```
test = datetime.strptime('2013-11-05T20:24:51+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z')
```

I get

```
ValueError: time data '2013-11-05T20:24:51+0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z'`
```

Comment: If you do that often and dislikes writing strptime expressions as I do, try http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Comment: Yep--definitely a duplicate. When I originally posted the question, I didn't realize it was in ISO 8601 format, so that question wasn't showing up when I searched. Feel free to close/merge or whatever is appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%Z`  is the wrong directive here.

Try this

```
datetime.strptime('2013-11-05T20:24:51+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%f')
```

[More here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2013-11-05T20:24:51+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2013-11-05T20:24:51+0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z'
>>> datetime.strptime('2013-11-05T20:24:51+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%f')
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 20, 24, 51)
```

Comment: Good catch that `%Z` is wrong. Although it's not `%f`--that's a totally different value, it should actually be `%z`.

Comment: @JeffWidman True, but `%z` gives: `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%z'`

Comment: Weird. According to the docs, %z should work... any idea why it doesn't?

Comment: @JeffWidman - Not a clue.

Comment: Python's `datetime` unfortately only supports `%z` for representing dates, but not for parsing them. Found this out myself a while ago the hard way.

Comment: and it seems like it is fixed for > python3.2

Comment: Good to know. I think for <=2.7 `python-dateutil` is still the way to go.

Comment: `%f` is *milliseconds*, not a timezone offset.

Comment: `%f` is the wrong directive. It might produce wrong result for values different from `+0000`.